# I need a dropdown list based on parent using ajax in Laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Controller Function Code

```
public function siteadmin_get_subcategory(Request $request)
{

    $product_id = $request->input('product');   

    $sub_category=array(
        'product_id'=>$product_id,
    );
    $return = Category_model::get_subcategory($sub_category);       
    //return view('siteadmin.get-subcategory',['sub_category' => $sub_category]);
    return view('siteadmin.get-subcategory',['sub_category' => $sub_category]);

}
```

Model Function Code (which gets subcategory on product id)

```
public static get_subcategory($sub_category)
{
    return DB::table('le_product')->where('product_id', '=', $sub_category)->get();

}
```

View JavaScript Code

This is my Ajax concept for Dropdown list based on parent

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product_id').change(function(){
        var product = $('#product_id').val();
        if(product != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:"<?php echo base_url('SiteadminController/siteadmin_getsub_category')?>",
                data: { id:product },
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#subcategory').html(returndata);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting? what not working?

Comment: Ajax function is not working it shows all category.i dont knw how to use an ajax in laravel5

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the correct URL in your AJAX:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#product_id').change(function(){
        var product = $('#product_id').val();
        if(product != 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:"<?php echo action('SiteadminController@siteadmin_getsub_category')?>",
                data: { id:product },
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#subcategory').html(returndata);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Also AJAX is expecting JSON, from what I see, you will return HTML. So you need to make a Controller action to return JSON.

Comment: Did you define a route for that? Do you have some basic Laravel understanding?

Comment: ya..im new in laravel5

Comment: I am afraid you need tor read more about how to add routes, start with the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Answer (score 0):

get_subcategory1

```
public function get_subcategory1()
    {
      /*$product_id = $request->input('product_id');
      $data=array(
                'product_id'=>$product_id,
                );*/
    //$get_subcategory1 = Category_model::get_subcategory1();
    return view('siteadmin.get-subcategory1');
    }
```

Comment: Please add that to the main question, not to an answer.